# Изменение первого View Controller

Tags: xcode, ios, apple

Добрый день.

Заголовок не очень корректный, но коротко описать вопрос достаточно трудно.
Итак, при запуске проекта в xcode запускается первый View Controller. На нем я расположил две кнопки, их действие примерно такое: при нажатии на первую открывается View Controllrer номер 2, при нажатии на вторую - View Controller номер 3. Таким образом пользователь выбрал, какой веткой приложения он будет пользоваться. И теперь при открытии приложения должен запускаться не экран выбора (который с двумя кнопками), а один из View Controller'ов: 2-й или 3-й, в соответствии с выбором пользователя. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Помогите, пожалуйста, просто больше некуда обратиться, в гугле же такой вопрос не задашь...
Спасибо, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Руслан, как я понял, вопрос касается сохранения выбора пользователя. Могу подсказать такой вариант: хранение настроек приложения с помощью класса NSUserDefaults в plist файле. Вот ссылка: http://www.imaladec.com/story/nsuserdefaults

Пользователь сделал выбор, выбор сохранился в файл, при следующем запуске приложения считываешь данные из файла и определяешь дальнейшие действия - окно 2 или 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет описания кода, отвечающего за переход к другому контроллеру. Ну да ладно.

Есть несколько вариантов:

- через navigationController. Проверка сохранённого параметра и:

  [navigationController pushViewController:anyController animated:YES];
- через container view. [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). Проверка и:

  [self addChildViewController:anyController];

  [self.view addSubview:anyController.view];
- или можно дёргать rootViewController у главного окна, это если выбор один раз делается за жизнь приложения.

Хранить значения можно тоже множеством вариантов. Это найти не сложно.

Если нужна возможность возврата к выбору "ветки", то первый или второй вариант отлично подойдут в зависимости от других потребностей.

ЗЫ. Гадкий же тут редактор сообщений.